# Saving values containing comma's in a HTML Multiple select

Tags: html, asp.net, html-select

I have a HTML multiple select being used which caused no issue until a selection with a comma was entered. When saving / loading the values are split by ',' into a list. Therefore causing an issue

I have tried to find a way of possibly changing the character that is being used to split the values when the form is posted but came to a dead end.

Would be very grateful if someone has any insight into this.

Thanks in advance.

---Update with Code---

The control is created dynamically

```
Dim SelectName1 As New HtmlSelect 
SelectName1.ID = "SelectName" & id 
SelectName1.Name = "SelectName" 
SelectName1.Multiple = True
```

and filled by looping though the values.

```
For Each value As String In Request.Form(idToFind).Split(",") 
If Not IsDBNull(SelectName.Items.FindByValue(value)) Then....
```

I cannot add any more code than that, Apologies

Comment: please add some source :)

Comment: Due to the nature of my work i cannot add a great deal of code however I have attached a bit which should help. The control is created dynamically 

        Dim SelectName1 As New HtmlSelect
        SelectName1 .ID = "SelectName" & id
        SelectName1 .Name = "SelectName" 
        SelectName1 .Multiple = True

and filled by looping though the values.

For Each value As String In Request.Form(idToFind).Split(",")
       If Not IsDBNull(SelectName.Items.FindByValue(value)) Then....

I cannot add any more code than that, Apologies

Comment: @SamBlake please add your code to your post. You can doing that by using the edit link unerneath your post. After that you can delte your last comment.

Comment: @Reporter Sorry, New to this, I have updated the question to include code

Answer (score 0):

After updating the question by add code, I think the available options are limited:

1. Create an extra Javascript method, that stores the selected values in a json object and store it into a hidden input field. I'm not an expert in asp.net, though I'm sure there exists a method to parse json objects from a string.
2. Create an extra javascript method, that concatinating all values to a String and store it into a hidden input field. With creation of a single string, you can define your own delimiter.

After that, add this extra Javascript mehod to the event `onSubmit`. Then submit the form and read the value from hidden input field.

P.S. In my eyes the second idea is more simple to create, than the first one. And maybe there are better ways.